# Move Ellipse Mask with mouseclick

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have an image sequence taken from a screencasted (2D)video game and there is a moving object (projectile). I want to add a lens flare effect to this projectile, therefore i wanna an ellipse mask that covers it for every frame. I need to to add keyframes for many frames and I have to type and adjust the values by hand in the x-/y-value fields which is quiet tedious (600 frames). Is there an easier way to do this? (Motion tracking doesnt work well for me by the way - too pixeled i guess)
I wonder if it is somehow possible to click on the image and the coordinates get copied into the x-/y- value fields in the ellipse mask node.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can manually move the mask with the video behind it in the UV/Image editor, you can keyframe each move. Try doing the extreme keyframes (large gaps between keys) then go back and insert new keys where the track drifts away. Otherwise try the tracker again, it might be that you aren't using quite right.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the mask in the UV Image Editor and it is really easy still tedious though.
I also tried again the Motion Tracking. This time it worked quite well... weird :S